# how to reference a cell programmatically in a loop with axlsx

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I want to programmatically add rows to my worksheet that reference other cells within the same row.  I've done this:

```
require 'axlsx'

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'Foo') do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row(['i', 'i*2'])
    for i in 1..10 do
      sheet.add_row([i, "=A#{i+1} * 2"])
    end
  end
  p.serialize('test.xlsx')
end
```

Is there a better way to do this, that doesn't involve keeping track of which row I'm on?

Comment: You are adding rows into your worksheet. To insert sheets in `AXLSX` you don't need to specify any index. `sheet.add_row([array of values])` is all you are using. I can't see where are 'rows' being tracked here. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Look at the generated spreadsheet.  I have one column with the numbers 1 to 10, and another column populated with formulas to multiply the numbers in the first column by 2.  I'm looking for a better way to generate the cell references in the second column (A2, A3, A4, ...).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to track every individual row for these tasks. There are excel functions for many of them that can be easily found over the Internet.

In your specific case, You can use this:

```
sheet.add_row([i,"=A:A * 2"])  # No need to iterate over the rows.
```

Here, `A:A` means that "Use Cells A1, A2, A3, A4 ..... "